# How to augment dataset by adding rows via huggingface datasets?

Tags: python, huggingface-datasets

I have a dataset with 113287 train rows. Each 'caption' field is however an array with multiple strings. I would like to flatmap this array and add new rows.

The documentation for datasets states that the [batch mapping feature](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/about_map_batch#map) may be used to achieve this:

> This means you can concatenate your examples, divide it up, and even add more examples!

```py
from datasets import load_dataset

dataset_name = "Jotschi/coco-karpathy-opus-de"
coco_dataset = load_dataset(dataset_name)

def chunk_examples(entry):
    captions = [caption for caption in entry["caption"][0]]
    return {"caption": captions}

print(coco_dataset)
chunked_dataset = coco_dataset.map(chunk_examples, batched=True, num_proc=4,
                      remove_columns=["image_id", "caption", "image"])
print(chunked_dataset)
print(len(chunked_dataset['train']))
```

```
DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['caption', 'image_id', 'image'],
        num_rows: 113287
    })
    validation: Dataset({
        features: ['caption', 'image_id', 'image'],
        num_rows: 5000
    })
    test: Dataset({
        features: ['caption', 'image_id', 'image'],
        num_rows: 5000
    })
})
DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['caption'],
        num_rows: 464
    })
    validation: Dataset({
        features: ['caption'],
        num_rows: 40
    })
    test: Dataset({
        features: ['caption'],
        num_rows: 40
    })
})
464
```

The problem that I'm having is that the resulting dataset does not contain the expected amount of rows.

It states `num_rows: 464` have been added. I suspect this to be the batches. How can I normalize this back into a "regular" dataset? Is there something wrong with my mapping function?

- datasets==2.18.0

Answer (score 0):

My mapping function was incorrect. I was only accessing the first entry via `[0]`.

```py
def chunk_examples(batch):
    captions = []
    for row in batch["caption"]:
        captions += row
    return {"caption": captions}
```

Now it yields:

```
DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['caption'],
        num_rows: 453460
    })
    validation: Dataset({
        features: ['caption'],
        num_rows: 25010
    })
    test: Dataset({
        features: ['caption'],
        num_rows: 25010
    })
})
453460
```